# Compare two lists and replace value in third list if equal

Tags: python, list, append

I am currently doing an online beginners course in Python and am stuck with this one element.

I have

```
listA = ['a','d','g','p','l','g','r','e']

listB = ['a','p','p','l','e']

listC = ['_','_','_','_','_']
```

I am comparing letters in list a to see if they are in list B, and if true then replace the same index in list C with that letter.The following code is in a function:

```html
for a in listA:
        for b in listB:
            if a==b:
                listC.append(listB.index(b))
    stringC = str(listC)    
    print(stringC)
```

The problem is that list C gets appended at the correct place, but with the int value of the index.

How can I replace the letter and not the index value?

Many Thanks!

Comment: append(thing) appends thing to list.

Comment: Do you want to check if the location of element in a and b also match or just if the element is present in b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do reverse search without the need of calling index, which makes it much faster (and specially if listA is longer than listB the search will be even shorter) and finally use list comprehension (which again is faster than loop):

```
listC = [x if x in listA else '_' for x in listB]
```

Also note that, this way handling duplicates is automatic and much easier.

output for your example:

```
listC
['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']
```

Comment: Hi this was awesome, but I did miss the duplicate p... any ideas on how to get both? Thanks a mil!

Comment: @KarinJansevanRensburg This answer gets both  (see the output I posted). Did you only want one of them?

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, I appreciate the help. I did needed both occurrences. I see that you used comprehension, something I have to get stuck into a bit more to gain confidence in writing it that way. Seems simple enough now that I see the solution. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use that :

```
listA=['a','d','g','p','l','g','r','e']

listB=['a','p','p','l','e']

listC=['','','','','_']

for a in range(len(listA)):
    letter = listA[a]
    if letter in listB:
        listC[listB.index(letter)] = letter
stringC = str(listC)
print(stringC)
```

It is faster, easier to understand, and works (even though I'm not totally sure I understood your question)..

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it was great, I did miss an instance where there were two of the same letter and the code skipped over the second p... any advise on how to correct this? Thanks so much!

Comment: That's because "index()" returns the FIRST occurence of the character in the array. You can either progressively remove chars in listB with "pop(index)", or use another array to store if you've already seen the letter or not.

Comment: It depands on your usage. Message me with your precise needs and I'll help you further.

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with this and pop(index). That should help me walk through the code. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question, you don't want to append to `listC`, but instead you want to modify elements of listC:

```
for a in listA:
    if a in listB:
        listC[listB.index(a)] = a
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching trying to compare the location of the characters too

```
listA=['a','d','g','p','l','g','r','e']

listB=['a','p','p','l','e']

listC=['','','','','_']

minlen = min(len(listA), len(listB))
for elem in range(minlen):
    if listA[elem] == listB[elem]:
        listC[listB.index(listA[elem])] = listA[elem]
print("{}".format(listC))
```

If checking only if they are available answer by Wiseman looks good

Answer (score 0):

Normally this should do:

```py
listA=['a','d','g','p','l','g','r','e']
listB=['a','p','p','l','e']
listC=['','','','','_']
 
for a in listA:
    for b in listB:
        if a==b:
                listC[listB.index(b)] = b
 
listC    
#Outputs
['a', 'p', '', 'l', 'e']
```

But if you instead want not to escape duplicate items in listC, then a bit of modification is required:

```py
for a in listA:
    for b in listB:
        if a==b:
            if b in listC:
                listC[(listC.index(b)+1)] = b
            else:
                    listC[listB.index(b)] = b
```

Note that this will also fail if you have listB=['a','p','p','p','l','e']. Then better approach would be wrapping it into a recursive function.

Comment: thanks! any ideas on recursive for this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```py
> listA=['a','d','g','p','l','g','r','e']
> listB=['a','p','p','l','e']
> listC=['','','','','_']

> for index, value in enumerate(listB):
>     listC[index] = listB[index] if value in listA else listC[index]


> print(listC)
['a','p','p','l','e']
```